# ggplot2 clips data in stat_density (density plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

data file: http://ubuntuone.com/3x5z4kFEUcVUB8KXYjICpD

Plotting the above data like this clips some of it:

```
tc = read.table('tertiary-tc.csv', header=T, sep=',')
library(ggplot2)
old <- theme_set(theme_bw())
pg <- ggplot(tertiary, aes(Conductivity)) + stat_density(geom = 'path'
    , position = 'identity') + facet_wrap(~Lithology)
print(pg)
```

whereas this does not:

```
library(lattice) 
densityplot(~Conductivity | Lithology
    , data = tc
    , groups=Lithology
    , plot.points=T
    , ref = T
    , main="Density plot"
    , auto.key=F
    , scales=list(tck=-1))  # set to a negative to plot inside ticks? Works!
dev.off()
```

The points not plotted (only looked quickly at it) are two points classed as 'dolomite' under the Lithology column. Is ggplot2 not plotting them as they are off-scale? Or because there are only two points?

Comment: only two points is the problem (`stat_density` has `if (n < 3) return(data.frame())`). Maybe try to compute the density manually beforehand with say `plyr::ddply`

Comment: @hadley why does stat_density reject two point data?

Comment: thanks @baptiste, I hope plyr won't take long to learn to use.

Comment: Of course, doing a kernel density plot with only two data points, probably isn't the best idea ;)

Comment: @csgillespie, i know, but it is more about the data display in this case. I wouldn't mind if just the points are displayed, but then it would be a bit incongruous with the rest of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might get you started

```
density2 <- function(x, select, ...){
  n <- nrow(x)
  range <- range(x[[select]])
  xgrid <- seq(range[1], range[2], length=200)

  weight <- rep(1, n) / n
  d <- density(x[[select]], ...,
                  weight=weight, from=range[1], to=range[2])

  as.data.frame(d[c("x","y")])

}


summaries <- ddply(tc, "Lithology", density2, select="Conductivity")

 ggplot(summaries, aes(x, y))  + facet_wrap(~Lithology) +
  geom_path()
```

not sure why it looks trimmed somehow, I'm not familiar with `density()`

Comment: Very decent of you! Not much familiar with any of it myself. Looks like you've got a firm grasp to me.